# issues installing milia in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I need your help I'm trying to install milia in my project, but every time I try to run **rails g milia:install --org_email='example@somewhere.com'** it send me this error in my console.

```
/Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:701:in `block (2 levels) in skip_callback': Before process_action callback :authenticate_tenant! has not been defined (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:697:in `each'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:697:in `block in skip_callback'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:627:in `block in __update_callbacks'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:625:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:625:in `__update_callbacks'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:696:in `skip_callback'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:203:in `block (3 levels) in <module:ClassMethods>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:96:in `block in _insert_callbacks'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:95:in `each'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:95:in `_insert_callbacks'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:202:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ClassMethods>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/milia-1.3.1/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `<class:RegistrationsController>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/milia-1.3.1/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `<module:Milia>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/milia-1.3.1/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/milia-1.3.1/lib/milia/railtie.rb:11:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/adair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-
```

this is the setup: **Rails 5.2.2** and **ruby-2.5.3**, I run bundle install it works fine but when I try to install milia I got that error.

I will really appreciate if you can helpme.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `before_action: authenticate_tenant!` in your `application_controller.rb` file. This, and other setup instructions are in the [sample app documentation](https://github.com/jekuno/milia#sample-app)